# Disable "..." truncating for a UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield

I've been reviewing the documentation for UITextField and its options are much more limited than the UITextView.

I've run into a situation where I need to handle truncating the text by forcing the bounding box to be bigger so no truncation exists.

I cannot just use `.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` because this event is only allowed when the text box is at screen width. The truncation is happening when it's not full screen length.

Right now when the user types, I log each keystroke and make sure the UITextFields box expands to fit the text. However if I use a large font, the text is getting cut off still:

```
"THIS IS LARGE TEXT GETTING CUT O..."
```

Currently I log each keystroke and run this code to size it:

```
func adjustFrameWidthToFitText()
{
    var size = sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(CGFloat.max,height))
    frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, size.width + 7, frame.height)
}
```

However I still get the ... cut off in some places. Is there anyway to tell if the text is being truncated and override the behaviour causing said truncation?

(Solutions in Swift & Obj-c welcome!)

Based on the answer below I tried:

```
func adjustFrameWidthToFitText()
{
    var fontSize = font.pointSize
    var atr = [NSFontAttributeName:font]
    var textSize = NSString(string: text).sizeWithAttributes(atr)
    frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, textSize.width, frame.height)
}
```

But there is still truncation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging I found the root cause, and a shortcut.

Shortcut first:

```
func adjustFrameWidthToFitText()
{
    var size = intrinsicContentSize()
    frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, size.width, frame.height)
}
```

This gives me the size of the textfield.

The problem with my code was I was calculating the resize event BEFORE the character was added to the text. So my bounds were always being calculated before the latest keystroke was added to the string.

When I changed my logic

```
public func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        adjustFrameWidthToFitText()
        return true
    }
```

To

```
textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)
{
  adjustFrameWidthToFitText()
}
```

It works.

Voila!

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to 'move' truncating dots from right side to the left ?

Answer (score 1):

```
extension String {
    func sizeWithAttributes(atr: NSDictionary) -> CGSize {
        return NSString(string: self).sizeWithAttributes(atr)
    }
}

let size = textView.text.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttribute:textView.font])
```

This will return the exact size for the string including '\n' characters.

The you can use the size however you want.

**ADDED**

Also when I was using CATextLayer I had to add this to the attributes to get the rows, havent tested on UITextView or field though:

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineHeightMultiple = 1.05

..., NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style])
```

Comment: Ahh creating an NSString and getting the size data based on its current font and size. Brilliance at its finest. Going to tinker with this right now!

Comment: It works by just doing "". sizeWithAttributes([:]) aswell, but it just doesnt autocomplete it for you so I added it in an extension :)

Comment: I have added an update to my question. I tried your solution and I 'think' I set it up right (if I did not please let me know). However with the solution I tried, the truncation is still there.

Comment: If you already have the font you dont have to make a new one, replace fontType with font

Comment: I just did that actually, has no effect though (because its the same values)

Comment: It seems this comes to the same logic as before, its calculating the width of the font incorrectly (and different fonts have worse estimations than others). Odd...

Comment: Oh I read your question wrong, I thought you were having troubles with a UIText'View'. A textField can scale down the fontsize if needed so a truncation wont show.

Comment: Yes but I cannot do this unless the textbox is the same width of the screen. This occurs before I am allow to scale down the font. I need to not scale down my font.

Comment: Have you tried to add 1 width to the width? Maybe a ceil() can solve your problem, it only takes a fraction of a point for it to add the "..."

Comment: Yea I added up to +15 to the width but REALLy big fonts still have an issue.

Comment: Why is it so hard to get true width size ?:(

Comment: Hmm if sizeWithAttributes is not returning the right size then I dont know.

Comment: INTERESTING derp on my part. My original solution DOES work, and yours works as well. But an even SHORTER solution is size = intrinsicContentSize(). The problem was my re-size event was being called BEFORE the latest character was added to the string, so it was always calculating the size 1 character short. Will post answer